# Can I delete Windows 8 ESD file?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I've just installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview and runned diskcleanup in order to delete windows.OLD file and everything is OK, but now want I delete the remaining WindowsESD file.

Is there a way? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 15):

from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-windows_install/how-can-i-safely-delete-the-windowsesd-file/d844bd93-4904-4204-9524-f88887cc7c03

> We do not recommend to remove the WindowsESD folder. This folder is
>   used by Push Button Reset feature to reset your computer back to its
>   original install state.
>
> For Windows.old and other remaining setup files, you can run Disk
>   Cleanup , click Clean up system files and check “Previous Windows
>   Installation(s)” and “Temporary Windows Installation files” if
>   available.

Basically, Windows uses those files for the new Refresh and Reset options, so unless space is an extremely important thing to you, I wouldn't delete it.

If you really want to delete it, run disk cleanup, click "Clean up System Files," then check "Windows ESD Installation Files" (or in the consumer preview, just follow the second-paragraph instructions)

Answer (score 5):

or move it to different drive and create a shortcut name ESD to the correct folder. Tested and running fine.
I did try to put it on second partition of system drive, second drive of the system, not in the same drive of system. Both options are working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

When I run comprehensive Disk Cleanup, there is an option to remove ESD files (as a checkbox for various types of files to clean). In my opinion, this "MS-approved" delete option (vs. just hard deleting the folder from C:) is safe: should I need to reinstall Windows, I can download and install a fresh installation (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh), as shown in Settings/Update & Security/Recovery/More recovery options. Because I do not reset or reinstall Windows frequently, this lengthy but clean option is worth it, plus I get 5GB+ (the space used by the ESD folder) of extra space.