# Can I move Windows 8 C:\ESD folder?

Tags: windows-8

I'm preparing to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8, and I am tight for space on my `C:\` drive, which is an SSD displaying its total size as 111 GB.

I want to maximise the free space, as I know that I'll end up with a `C:\Windows.old` folder for some time.

Having already purchased the Windows 8 upgrade, I have a `C:\ESD` folder which occupies 2.6 GB.

I see from [Can I delete Windows 8 ESD file?](https://superuser.com/q/396268/17574) that I won't be able to delete this folder, even after the upgrade, as Windows uses those files for the new Refresh and Reset options.

**But is it OK to move this folder from `C:\ESD` to `D:\ESD`?**

By "OK", I mean:

- Will I be able to install the Windows 8 upgrade successfully, if I have moved it to D:
- Will Refresh and Reset work OK, in Windows 8, if the ESD folder is in a location other than `C:\ESD`?

Comment: Just moving it definitely won't work. It MAY work if you move it and create a symbolic link on `C:`, but I haven't tested it - just an idea.

Comment: I can't see any reason why a symbolic link wouldn't fix this issue. In theory, the Windows 8 upgrade will just follow the path of the ESD folder regardless of where exactly it resides on a disk. So I would go with that.

Comment: Why can't you just delete the Windows.old folder after the upgrade?

Comment: @Cmorse See the link in my question. It is needed for Refresh and Reset.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft probably didn't design the ESD folder to be moved however:

You can move the folder to your other Partition/Drive and create a shortcut to the folder in the place the ESD folder was.

Example:

1. Move the `C:\ESD` to `D:\ESD`
2. Create a shortcurt in `C:\` named `ESD` and point it to `D:\ESD`:

   `mklink /j C:\ESD D:\ESD`

That should work.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am ideally looking for stronger confirmation than "should work". Have you actually tested it out, including doing a Refresh or Rest?

Comment: Yes I have had to do that personally. As long as you point to the right folder and name the shortcut correctly it will work.

Comment: Ah right, OK, that's really helpful to know. Thank you.

Comment: Actually a shortcut probably won't work because a shortcut is actually a `.lnk` file that explorer.exe knows, but you can now use `mklink /D` to create a symbolic link to another directory. Since this works as the filesystem level, it has a much higher chance or working.